# Display ALL the columns from table that doesn`t contain the Primary Keys

Tags: sql, primary-key, display

I`ve got this query to do.
Display ALL the columns from table named 'somehow' that are not primary keys.

This is how I am trying to obtain the column headers that differ from the Primary Key ID Column :

```
SELECT cols.column_name 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k 
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type <> 'PRIMARY KEY' 
AND t.table_schema='mydb' 
AND t.table_name='somehow'
```

Something is not right since I get an SQL Error. What am I doing wrong?

Update :

```
SELECT k.column_name 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type <> 'PRIMARY' 
AND t.table_schema='mydb' 
AND t.table_name='somehow'
```

This shows exactly what I don`t want to get as a result (The Primary Key ) I need everything else to be shown :(

Comment: mySQL, @RyanVincent

Comment: unfortunately no , cols is not defined as an alias anywhere. I just thought that cols is by default used to select multiple columns for a Table. To be honest ,I do not know where to declare it. I am just using those command lines to make my query. @RyanVincent

Comment: change to `k.column_name`

Comment: Point taken Ryan,but the thing is that I want to select and display all the Columns (headers) that are different from the IDshomehow (primary key container) , I have tried with SELECT *column_name and then the rest of the code , but I still get an error.@RyanVincent

Comment: Now the code Runs with k.column_name but the result is an empty one..I know that it should have displayed all the columns except the column that holds the Primary Keys (IDsomehow).@RyanVincent

Comment: If I use the following code : `SELECT k.column_name 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type <> 'PRIMARY' 
AND t.table_schema='mydb' 
AND t.table_name='somehow'` . I get exactly the thing I`m not looking for to display ( I obtain the column name of the primary key and I need everything else except the primary key). I don`t know what I need to use from the schema :( @RyanVincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All table columns can be found in MySQL's system table `columns`. Its `column_key` field contains 'PRI' in case a column is part of the primary key. Hence:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'mydb' 
   and table_name = 'somehow'
   and column_key <> 'PRI';
```